# How to call method in child component from parent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a parent and a child component. An example is below:

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  int stateVar = 1;

  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        FlatButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
          onPressed: () {
            setState() {
              stateVar = stateVar + 1;
              }
            }
          ),
         Child()
        ]
      )
    )
}
```

And the child component is:

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {

  methodToCall() {
    print("Method called");
  }

  return Container(
    child: Text("Child text")
    )
}
```

I want to call the method `methodToCall` inside the childcomponent from the parent component whenever the value of state variable `stateVar` changes in the parent.

Doing some research online, I found one way to do it is using `GlobalKey` as in the blog: https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/how-to-call-method-of-a-child-widget-from-parent-in-flutter

But this is not working, as the two components are in different files, and difficult to handle keys. One other method was to use `useEffect` but that didn't work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why does _childState have Child() in its container??

Comment: That was a typo. Updated the question

Comment: Can't you put `methodToCall` inside `Child` and then make an object of Child inside `_ParentState` (before return) and call its method from onPressed? + Where is build method?

Comment: Not sure how. Are you asking to make it a public method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `Parent` class extending `ChangeNotifier` and make `Children` class listening to `Parent` notifications.

See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier